# d3js Heatmap - month calendar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I'm trying to create a d3.js heatmap month calendar. That only shows 1 month - and is toggled by chevrons left/right. I want to increase the temperature of the day if there is a "booking" for a medical professional.

So the data to overlay onto the month calendar may look something like this to showcase the schedule for that person.

I need to add the chevrons and toggle between months and return the clicked date now.

27th July 2023
-latest codebase
https://jsfiddle.net/16vqcdar/6/

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Heatmap d3</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>



    <script>
      var data = [{
          "date": "2023-07-10",
          "value": "211"
        },{
          "date": "2023-07-20",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-21",
          "value": "5"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-22",
          "value": "5"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-23",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-24",
          "value": "8"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-25",
          "value": "3"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-26",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]


      var width = 300,
        height = 450,
        cellSize = 35; // cell size
      week_days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
      month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

      var day = d3.timeFormat("%w"),
        week = d3.timeFormat("%U"),
        format = d3.timeFormat("%Y%m%d");
      parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y%m%d").parse;

      var color = d3.scaleLinear().range(["white", '#002b53'])
        .domain([0, 1])

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("class", "calendar")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 10)");

      var leg = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "leg")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 10)");

      var chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("transform", "translate(25, -850)");
      //
      const d = new Date();
      let name = month[d.getMonth()];
      //console.log("name", name);


      let pickedYear = 2023;
      let pickedMonth = 7; //July

      const daysInMonth = (year, month) => new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

      //console.log("daysInMonth", daysInMonth(pickedYear, pickedMonth));

      let dz = 1;
      //console.log("xx", d3.timeDays(new Date(pickedYear+"-"+pickedMonth+"-1"), new Date(pickedYear+"-"+pickedMonth+"-31")) )

      //console.log("ccccc",  new Date(pickedYear+"-"+pickedMonth+"-"+daysInMonth)  )

      function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
          month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
          day = '' + d.getDate(),
          year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2)
          month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2)
          day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('-');
      }

      function opacityCal(val) {
        var opacity = 0.1;

        opacity = opacity * val;

        //if val is 0 - consider it a spare day no change in opacity
        if (val === 0 || val >= 10) {
          opacity = 1;
        }

        return opacity;
      }

      //
      var padding = 5;

      var rect = chart.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function(d) {
          return d3.timeDays(new Date("2023-07-1"), new Date("2023-07-31"));
        })
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "day " + "date" + formatDate(d);
        })
        .attr("data-date", function(d) {
          return formatDate(d);
        })
        .attr("width", cellSize)
        .attr("height", cellSize)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            //console.log("d", d)
          return day(d) * cellSize;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return week(d) * cellSize;
        })
        .attr("fill", '#f2f2f2')
        .attr("stroke", 'white')
        .attr("stroke-width", '7')
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(event.currentTarget)
            .style("fill", "#d9e3a6");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(event.currentTarget)
            .style("fill", "#f2f2f2");
        })
        .on("click", function(d,i){
            let date = d3.select(event.currentTarget).attr("data-date");
            console.log("date", date)
            return date;
        })
        .datum(format);

      var legend = leg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(week_days)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate(" + (((i + 1) * 35) + 5) + ",0)";
        });

      legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
          return week_days[i]
        })
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dy", "-.25em")
        .text(function(d, i) {
          return week_days[i]
        });


      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


        d3.selectAll('.' + "date" + formatDate(data[i].date))
          .attr("fill", "#f8600d")
          .attr("opacity", opacityCal(parseInt(data[i].value)))
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(event.currentTarget)
              .style("fill", "#d9e3a6")
              .attr("opacity", 1)
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(event.currentTarget)
              .style("fill", "#f8600d")
              .attr("opacity", opacityCal(parseInt(data[i].value)))
          })

      }

    </script>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: d3 is a data visualization library. Why do you need it for this? Wouln't it be much easier to use calendar or datepicker made by yourself (or not) and map the heat values to colours?

Comment: Why cant d3.js make rectangles and add the colors accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the chart - week number in reference to the current month. The chart now works as follows. When used as a react component - the current month is picked with the help of buttons prev and next. The d3js heatmap calendar then changes and highlights the schedule intensity from the data prop.

Welcome any enhancements - like pre-selecting the dates.

https://jsfiddle.net/16vqcdar/7/

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Heatmap d3</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>



    <script>
      var data = [{
          "date": "2023-07-10",
          "value": "211"
        },{
          "date": "2023-07-20",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-21",
          "value": "5"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-22",
          "value": "5"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-23",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-24",
          "value": "8"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-25",
          "value": "3"
        },
        {
          "date": "2023-07-26",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]





    var currentTime = "2023-07-28";
    //console.log("currentTime", currentTime)
    var currentTimeDate = new Date(currentTime);
    //console.log("currentTimeDate", currentTimeDate)

        
        var w = parseInt(300, 10),
            h = parseInt(300, 10);

        //var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.state.theme);


        var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 30, left: 20},
            width = w - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;                


        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr('class', 'heatmapcalendarholder')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var cellSize = 35; // cell size
      var week_days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
      var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

      var day = d3.timeFormat("%w"),
        week = d3.timeFormat("%U"),
        format = d3.timeFormat("%Y%m%d");
      var parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y%m%d").parse;

      //console.log("week", week(new Date("01-01-2023")))
      //console.log("week", week(new Date("07-01-2023")))

      //console.log("week", weekOfTheMonth(new Date("01-01-2023")))
      //console.log("week", weekOfTheMonth(new Date("07-01-2023")))
     

      //var color = d3.scaleLinear().range(["white", '#002b53'])
      //  .domain([0, 1])

        /*
      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("class", "calendar")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 10)");
        */

      var leg = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "leg")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10, 10)");

      var chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("transform", "translate(25, 20)");
      //
      const d = new Date();
      let name = month[d.getMonth()];
      //console.log("name", name);

      const daysInMonth = (year, month) => new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();


      let pickedYear = currentTimeDate.getFullYear().toString();//"2023";
      let pickedMonth = (currentTimeDate.getMonth()+1).toString()//"07"; //July
      //console.log("pickedYear", pickedYear)
            //console.log("pickedMonth", pickedMonth)

      let startDate = pickedYear+"-0"+pickedMonth+"-1";
      let endDate = pickedYear+"-0"+pickedMonth+"-"+daysInMonth(pickedYear, pickedMonth);

      //console.log("endDate", endDate);

        //console.log("daysInMonth", daysInMonth(pickedYear, pickedMonth));

      //let dz = 1;
      //console.log("xx", d3.timeDays(new Date(pickedYear+"-"+pickedMonth+"-1"), new Date(pickedYear+"-"+pickedMonth+"-31")) )

      //console.log("ccccc",  new Date(pickedYear+"-"+pickedMonth+"-"+daysInMonth)  )

         function weekOfTheMonth(date) {
              //let weekN = week(date);
              //console.log("date--", date)
              //console.log("weekN", weekN)

              const startWeekDayIndex = 0; // 1 MonthDay 0 Sundays
              const firstDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
              const firstDay = firstDate.getDay();

              let weekNumber = Math.ceil((date.getDate() + firstDay) / 7);
              //console.log("weekNumber", weekNumber)

              if (startWeekDayIndex === 1) {
                if (date.getDay() === 0 && date.getDate() > 1) {
                  weekNumber -= 1;
                }

                if (firstDate.getDate() === 1 && firstDay === 0 && date.getDate() > 1) {
                  weekNumber += 1;
                }
              }
              return weekNumber;
        }


      function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
          month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
          day = '' + d.getDate(),
          year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2)
          month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2)
          day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('-');
      }

      function opacityCal(val) {
        var opacity = 0.1;

        opacity = opacity * val;

        //if val is 0 - consider it a spare day no change in opacity
        if (val === 0 || val >= 10) {
          opacity = 1;
        }

        return opacity;
      }

      //
      let that = this;
      //var padding = 5;
      //console.log("TIMEINDAYS", d3.timeDays(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate)))

      var rect = chart.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function(d) {
          return d3.timeDays(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
        })
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "day " + "date" + formatDate(d);
        })
        .attr("data-date", function(d) {
          return formatDate(d);
        })
        .attr("width", cellSize)
        .attr("height", cellSize)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            //console.log("d", d)
          return day(d) * cellSize;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            //console.log("d", d)
          return weekOfTheMonth(d) * cellSize;
        })
        .attr("fill", '#f2f2f2')
        .attr("stroke", 'white')
        .attr("stroke-width", '7')
        .on("mouseover", function(event) {
          d3.select(event.currentTarget)
            .style("fill", "#d9e3a6");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(event) {
          d3.select(event.currentTarget)
            .style("fill", "#f2f2f2");
        })
        .on("click", function(event){
            let date = d3.select(event.currentTarget).attr("data-date");
            console.log("date", date)
            //return date;
            //that.props.pickedDate(date);
        })
        .datum(format);

      var legend = leg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(week_days)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
          return "translate(" + (((i + 1) * 35) + 5) + ",0)";
        });

      legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
          return week_days[i]
        })
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dy", "-.25em")
        .text(function(d, i) {
          return week_days[i]
        });


      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


        d3.selectAll(".date" + formatDate(data[i].date))
          .attr("fill", "#f8600d")
          .attr("opacity", opacityCal(parseInt(data[i].value)))
          .on("mouseover", function(event) {
            d3.select(event.currentTarget)
              .style("fill", "#d9e3a6")
              .attr("opacity", 1)
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(event) {
            d3.select(event.currentTarget)
              .style("fill", "#f8600d")
              .attr("opacity", opacityCal(parseInt(data[i].value)))
          })

      }


    </script>



  </body>

</html>
```